# Download issues with Android Marketplace: "Download unsuccessful"

Tags: google-play-store

Archos 43 Internet Tablet owner here.

I've been happily using the Google Android Marketplace since purchasing this device, but recently, my application downloads and updates are not working.  Either the download attempts to start and nothing happens, or I immediately get a "Download unsuccessful" message.  I'm not sure what changed to make this happen.

Today, I also got a PowerAMP error indicating that they can't verify my PowerAMP license (Cause: Android Market response- ERROR CONTACTING SERVER).

Maybe this is a firmware issue?  Currently using Firmware 2.3.26 (Android 2.2.1).

No issues with AppsLib or Amazon App Store, but some apps are only on the Android Marketplace, and I want to use them!

Any help troubleshooting this is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try going to `Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> All` and clearing the data for the Market (you may need to Force Close it first), then reboot your phone. This has fixed a similar issue for me before.

I think the PowerAMP issue is unrelated, their server is probably down temporarily.

Comment: Already cleared the "Market" data twice.  I was hoping that would fix it, but no dice.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  I'm not sure what else to suggest besides a factory reset.  I'm assuming you have lots of space free on your internal storage?

Comment: Bummer.  Should I choose "Reset Android" or "Full reinitialization?"  One deletes settings and apps, the other deletes everything.

Comment: I would probably go for the full, but who knows.  For some people it solves the issue and for others it doesn't.

Comment: Do I lose purchased apps, or can they be re-downloaded?

Comment: @Zoot all purchases are tied to your Google account.  You will be able to re-download them without charge

Comment: OK.  I chose "reset Android" and loaded the Market again (through ArcTools), and everything seems to be working fine this time around.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced similar problem. The solution is similar but key point is you also have to clear the download manager cache and force stop it.

Here is the guide if you want step by step help:
http://techspalace.blogspot.com/2011/08/solved-download-unsuccessful-on-android.html