# Issues canceling downloads in Market

Tags: google-play-store, cyanogenmod, downloading

All of a sudden a few days ago, I went into the Market for the first time in ages to download a new app. It said the app would be downloaded, but when I went back several hours later, it had not downloaded. I looked in the Downloads section of the market, and there were about 6 updates trying to download (which I hadn't approved - I don't have automatic downloads set, just notification of new updates with manual download). I want to cancel these downloads, but it will not happen. I long-press on the app name and choose Cancel, but nothing happens. I've even rebooted the phone, but the unwanted downloads are still there, saying Starting Download - this is after 3 days.

I've seen [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3547/market-app-downloads-always-fails-never-starts), [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8736/download-issues-with-android-marketplace-download-unsuccessful), and [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3933/cancel-all-market-updates-downloads-at-once), but none of them are exactly the same as my issue. The last two did have answers that I'd like to try - clearing the application data and cache for the market. Unfortunately, I don't see the Market as an app in my Manage Applications section. (I'm running CyanogenMod 5 on a rooted T-Mobile MyTouch G3.)

Is there any way I can access that application to clear the cache? Or any other way I can get the unwanted downloads to stop trying and go away?

Comment: I don't know how it works in CM but it has to be there somewhere.  It might be called "CM Market" or something.  Make sure you're not on a "Third-party Apps" tab or anything, since that won't list the first-party Market.

Comment: There is no Third-Party Apps tab that I can see; it's just a list of all apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the Market data from the command line like so:

`rm -r /data/data/com.android.vending/*`

Comment: OK, tried that in my terminal app; didn't work. The downloads are still there.

Comment: @EmmyS Hmm, strange. I would try ensuring that the Market app is not running, executing the command, and rebooting.  If that doesn't work I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: This will certainly remove your market preferences, specifically any toggles for 'auto-download' that you have made. For me, I have a Droid 3 and all the pre-installed crapware has that on by default, so every time I clear market data, I have to toggle all those apps off. This might not be a big deal to Emmy, but it's something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is limited to large apps, maybe the problem is the following:
http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/17824-google-maps-wont-install/page__p__175751#entry175751

The Market uses the same folder for cache as dalvik does, so you are limited to 5mb apps!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure they're all large apps, but I'll take a look at that. Thanks.

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry, it didn't. I ended up reinstalling CyanogenMod.